# NVIDIA CUDA on Windows Compact Embedded 7

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, windows-embedded-7

Is there a way to use NVIDIA CUDA in Windows Embedded Compact 7? I'm currently working on a system that processes video and would like to change from Windows 7 to Windows CE 7. However, I'm not sure about using CUDA. Windows Embedded Standard 7 works, but I was hoping to go lighter.

Answer (score 1):

Support for cuda is determined by the GPU used in the system and the driver.
If a newer Nvidia driver is working on Windows Compact Embedded 7 then yes, you will be able to use CUDA.
Though it looks like Nvidia is not supporting it anymore going by the supported driver list on microsoft.com
The only drivers are for a Nvidia Graphics Card from 2007 that doesn't support CUDA.
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/drivercatalog.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Windows Embedded Compact 7 is not a lighter version of Windows Embedded 7 Standard. It is a different operating system in the Windows CE line while standard is from the Windows NT line.

So the answer is no.